# Does variation in data density over time affect regression models?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, logistic-regression, linear-regression

So, I've been building data collectors for the stock market. Basically
this is just to give myself a resource that I can query as much as I
want and not get dinged by over usage. (the learning experience is
also a plus)

I'm curious though if the change in the frequency of data will skew
the results of a regression model (to keep things simple `y = price`
and `x = time_stamp`).

The problem comes in when the amount of data is considered. I have
the collectors recording the change in the stocks once a minute. For
data in the past that happened before I was collecting, I load the daily
open and close prices and whatever other information companies are
willing to share for free.

My question is, will the much more detailed data that I'm collecting
each minute  throw off or enhance the regression models that can be
created by just looking at the daily open and close prices?

I would assume that it would enhance it but, I would like to know if that's not the case and that in order to get an accurate measurement I would need to just use the interval that applies universally.

Here's an example chart to better explain what I mean.

[image: sample_plot]

Comment: There's not quite enough information provided to answer this question. Raw time-series are often transformed into rectangular data-sets in order for regression models to be applied to them.  Is this what you are proposing doing? Otherwise, time series analysis is usually achieved via smoothing, removal of periodic components (de-seasoning), and forecasting.  ARIMA is a routine that achieves all of the above procedures in a tidy form, but is not strictly regression.

Comment: @AN6U5 does the graph help?

Comment: Are you simply trying to forecast the time series? If not, what are you trying accomplish?

Comment: @AN6U5 yeah forecasting is the goal.